# How to update two users at the same time in updateUser Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm currently working on Keycloak version 21.0.2, and I'm in the process of customizing the **updateUser** function within the **UserResource** class. Specifically, as part of updating a user's email (let's say user2), I aim to prevent any other user from having the same email.

For instance, if user1 was previously created with the email "test@example.com," and user2 attempts to change their email to "test@example.com," I intend to disable user1.

Here's the relevant section of my code:

```
public Response updateSpecificUser(final UserRepresentation rep , UserModel user) {
    auth.users().requireManage(user);
    try {
        // ... same as updateUser function

        UserProfile profile = session.getProvider(UserProfileProvider.class).create(USER_API, attributes, user);
        Response response = validateUserProfile(profile, user, session);
        if (response != null) { return response; }

        profile.update(rep.getAttributes() != null);
        updateUserFromRep(profile, user, rep, session, true);
        RepresentationToModel.createCredentials(rep, session, realm, user, true);
        adminEvent.operation(OperationType.UPDATE).resourcePath(session.getContext().getUri()).representation(rep).success();
        return Response.noContent().build();
    } catch (Exception e) { ... }
}

@Path("test")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response test(@FormParam("email") String new_email) {
    auth.users().requireManage(user);

    // Change User2 which is the global variable user in UserResource class
    UserRepresentation rep2 = new UserRepresentation();
    rep2.setEmail(new_email);
    Response response2 = updateSpecificUser(rep2, user);

    // Change User1
            Usermodel existed_user = session.users().getUserByEmail(realm, new_email).findFirst().get();
    if (!Objects.equals(existed_user.getId(), user.getId())) {
        UserRepresentation rep = new UserRepresentation();
        HashMap<String, List<String>> attrinfo =
                (HashMap<String, List<String>>) existed_user.getAttributes().entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        attrinfo.put("Reason of Disable", Collections.singletonList("Same Email"));
        rep.setAttributes(attrinfo);
        rep.setEnabled(false);
        Response response = updateSpecificUser(rep, existed_user);
    }


    if (session.getTransactionManager().isActive()) {
        session.getTransactionManager().commit();
    }
...
}
```

However, despite implementing this, user1's enable does not seem to change. Any suggestions from anyone would be greatly appreciated.